# How to triple boot Ubuntu 14.04 and freeBSD 10?

Tags: dual-boot

Currently I am Using Ubuntu and Windows 7. Recently I Tried freeBSD in virtual machine and I loved FreeBSD.

Can I triple boot? ie. Ubuntu, Windows and FreeBSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add at the Grub2 menu, Freebsd.

1. Open a terminal,

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Run it:

   `$ sudo -i`
   `# nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom`

In the file you need to add these lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries. Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment. Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "FreeBSD" {
    insmod ufs2   
    set root=(hd0,1)
    chainloader +1
    }
```

3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.
4. Now just need to update the Grub

   `# update-grub`

   Note: Change these parameters: 
   `set root=(hd0,1)`
   That apply to your installation of FreeBSD